# Installing python packages with no installation directory acces and no pip/easy_install/virtual_env

Tags: python, module, installation, root, package

At work we have python installed, but no additional modules. I want to import some scipy modules but I have no access to the python directory for installation.

Similar questions have been asked on StackOverflow, but the answers always assumed easy install, pip or virtualenv were installed. At my workplace, none of these packages are installed. It's just the plain python installation and nothing else.

Is there still an option for me for installing modules in my local folder and calling them from python? If so, how do I go about it?

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly installing modules on your local folder, but a solution nonetheless:

I used to work for a company that used windows and didn't have admin access, so I ended up using [Portable python](http://portablepython.com/). 
It seems portable python is no longer mantained, but you can see some other portable python solutions on their site,  most of which you can run straight from your usb.

Comment: Thanks. I already have anaconda on my home PC. Can I simply install it to a USB drive?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try and tell us afterward :P .  Here are the last portable python distros just in case you want to give them a try.

Comment: I'll definately try and keep you posted!

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! Problem solved. I just got anaconda and installed to USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can download pip from here http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/ and install it without root privileges by typing:

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

This will install to directory with prefix $HOME/.local so the pip executable will be in the directory $HOME/.local/bin/pip, for your convenience you can add this directory to $PATH by adding to end of .bashrc file this string

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH
```

After this you can install any packages by typing

```
pip install package --user
```

---

Or you can alternatively compile the python distribution from source code and install to your home directory to directory $HOME/.local or $HOME/opt or any subfolder of $HOME you prefer, let's call this path $PREFIX. For doing this you have to download python source code from official site, unpack it and then run

```
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-shared
make install
```

And then add python binary to $PATH, python libraries to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, by adding to the end of $HOME/.bashrc file whit strings

```
 export PATH=$PREFIX/bin:$PATH
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib
```

and when after restarting bash you can also run

```
 python get-pip.py
```

and pip and will be installed automatically to your $PREFIX directory. And all other packages those you will install with pip will be automatically installed also to $PREFIX directory. This way is more involved, but it allows you to have the last version of python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I download the pip code and put it in a file get-pip.py in my local folder and then go to python shell and type python get-pip.py it simply says "invalid syntax". I also tried running it from the .py file but then it says "ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': closed". I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: You have to download this file not copying as a plain text because python is sensitive to Intends, if your browser does not download and shows like text you can run: wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: OK, that's what I did now, but it didn't change anything. Typing in the python shell still gives me invalid syntax and running the file gives me the same error :(

Comment: Which version of python do you have?

Comment: It's 2.7.1. Am I entering the text in the right place? I have IDLE GUI for Python. There's a shell window and an option for opening .py files. I've tried both.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are doing it correct with using idle. From bash it definitely will work. Open the terminal emulator, and go to directory where the downloaded get-pip.py is placed and just run in bash, not in idle of python interactive console,:  python get-pip.py --user

Comment: Ah...I'm not familiar with bash. What is it? Do I download it somewhere?

Comment: I assumed that you have Unix like os after you wrote that you don't have root privileges. But now i'm not sure about this. Which operating system do  you use?

Comment: I'm on windows 7. With root priviliges I meant that I cannot write to the c-drive. Sorry for the misunderstanding.